# Wordpress admin session auth with opencart?

Tags: php, wordpress, opencart

I have a Wordpress installation and a Opencart installation on my server. I want to integrate the admin-account of those installaltions so that I can use the login of Wordpress to also be authorised as the administrator of Opencart.

With Google I have figured out that I can make use of the wp-config.php file for this, but I have no idea of how to unset Opencart's own login feature in advantage of Wordpress. Any idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

Without going deeper, you may try placing hidden form areas which you get from `wp-login.php` inside the opencart and change opencart login page tpl file as it first sends login information to wplogin with ajax at background and then let opencart login goes on as usual.

Note that to use a logic like this both usernames and passwords should be same in both opencart and wordpress... (also maybe you can check wordpress login result and then let opencart login form posted with some extra effort)

Long (but maybe the real) solution lies in creation of a login session for one with another login form.